# Can't add more than one Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a SPA that implements modals.  I'm trying to create dropdowns for certain elements that have modals attached to them.  I want each dropdown to display a list of commands, and then a "link" to the modal.  I can implement the modals just fine.  The problem is with the dropdowns.  The page works fine when I implement the first dropdown, but when I try to implement the second dropdown, neither of them work.  I set the data-target attribute to see if that changed anything, but I am either not using it correctly or it's not part of the solution.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="row cluster" ng-repeat="cluster in clusterCtrl.clusters">  

    <!-- this dropdown breaks the other one -->

    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" data-target="#cluster">
        <h4 id="cluster" class="pointer dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
            {{cluster.name}}
        </h4>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Status</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Start</a><li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Stop</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="pointer" ng-click="openCluster()">Details</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  

    <!-- -->

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!-- START INSTANCE DISPLAY -->
        <div class="row">                                   
             <div class="col-xs-1 instance" ng-repeat="instance in instanceCtrl.instances">
                 <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" data-target="#instance">
                    <h6 id="instance" class="pointer dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                        {{instance.name}}
                    </h6>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Status</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Start</a><li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Stop</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a class="pointer" ng-click="openInstance()">Details</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
             </div>                                 
        </div>
        <!-- END INSTANCE DISPLAY -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you throw this into a plunkr?

Comment: I figured it out... Writing up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-target` attribute is not needed.  The problem lies in `dropdown is-open="status.isopen"`.  This is a unique attribute.  To fix it, you need to write a new controller for your dropdown.  Be sure not to name it `DropdownController` since that it an internal control to Bootstrap.

**dropdown-controller.js**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('DropdownCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.status = {
              isClusterOpen: false,
              isInstanceOpen: false,
            };

            $scope.toggled = function(open) {
              console.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
            };

            $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
              $event.preventDefault();
              $event.stopPropagation();
              $scope.status.isClusterOpen = !$scope.status.isClusterOpen;
              $scope.status.isInstanceOpen = !$scope.status.isInstanceOpen;
            }; 
        });
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="row cluster" ng-repeat="cluster in clusterCtrl.clusters">  

    <!-- Changed -->  
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-cluster-open="status.isClusterOpen" >
    <!-- -->

        <h4 id="cluster" class="pointer dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
            {{cluster.name}}
        </h4>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Status</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Start</a><li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Stop</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="pointer" ng-click="openCluster()">Details</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!-- START INSTANCE DISPLAY -->
        <div class="row">                                   
             <div class="col-xs-1 instance" ng-repeat="instance in instanceCtrl.instances">

                 <!-- Changed -->  
                 <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-instance-open="status.isInstanceOpen">
                 <!-- -->

                    <h6 id="instance" class="pointer dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                        {{instance.name}}
                    </h6>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Status</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Start</a><li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Stop</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a class="pointer" ng-click="openInstance()">Details</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
             </div>                                 
        </div>
        <!-- END INSTANCE DISPLAY -->
    </div>
</div>
```